# Augmented frequency scale of Term frequency as it appear on Wikipedia

Tags: computational-statistics, natural-language

The third definition of the tf(t, d) in Wikipedia is:

[image]

I was wondering, why would we want to scale to the range of 0.5..1?

Comment: Maybe http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/jzobel/fulltext/sigirforum98.pdf will answer your question?

Comment: Maybe someone else could explain better the argument that appears on page 9 of this dissertation: https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/7281/97-1626.pdf?sequence=1